# Drupal contact form is not displaying a theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, drupal-contact-form

So I've gone and customized the user login/pass/register pages Drupal 6 and no problems. However I now do the same thing with the contact mail page (contact module enabled) and all I get is the contact form and NO theme. What am I doing wrong?

```
function mytheme_theme() {
  return array(
    'user_login' => array(
      'template' => 'user-login',
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
    'user_register' => array(
      'template' => 'user-register',
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
    'user_pass' => array(
      'template' => 'user-pass',
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
    'contact_mail_page' => array(
      'template' => 'page-contact',
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To theme a full page you shouldn't need to add that item into your code at all (in fact, it may be the reason you're not getting any theme - your item is conflicting with the default behaviour).

Presuming the url for your contact page is "http://www.your-site.com/contact", just create page-contact.tpl.php in your theme directory (..and clear the theme registry, gets me every time).

This goes for all pages - create a template based on page.tpl.php, and named after the url arguments. For example, page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php will be used to theme http://www.your-site.com/taxonomy/term.

Comment: I tried to add a node-contact.tpl.php file but Drupal isn't using it.

Comment: EricP: there are a whole stack of reasons why it might not be working, but without knowing your setup, it's difficult to pinpoint. Upshot: node-contact.tpl.php to theme just the content of a page (which I assume is what you're trying to do) isn't a default template format. You can use node-<content-type>.tpl.php or node-<nid>.tpl.php to theme the content for specific types or individual nodes. 

If you want to re-theme just the content of a (non-node) contact form, the fastest option is to use a form_alter hook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a module rather than a theme. With drupal6 you can extend an exsisting theme, negating the need for you to try and override the theme for each item.

Have a look at base theme in the theme [.info](http://drupal.org/node/171205#base-theme) file, and the documentation on [creating your own theme](http://drupal.org/node/171179)